# Enum declaration in Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, enums

I'm compiling a c++ project in Eclipse, Linux.

The project was compiled in Windows in the past.

I have my declaration of enums like this:

```
enum nameofenum:UINT32
{
  one=0,
  two=1
}
```

The result is an error in eclipse.

1. What is the meaning of `:UINT32`?
2. How can I switch this declaration to Linux?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and pressing CTRL+K. Use the preview!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a [strongly typed enum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Strongly_typed_enumerations), which is a C++0x feature. Basically, it specifies the underlying type of the enumeration, so `one` and `two` will be `UINT32`s.

To compile it, you need a compiler that supports this particular part of the C++0x language. I believe [GCC 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)  and [Visual C++](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127230241/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx) supports strongly typed enums to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

The `: UINT32` declares the underlying type of the enumeration; it means that the enumeration will be represented by a `UINT32`.

This is a new C++ feature that is being added in C++0x called strongly typed enumerations.  Visual C++ has supported it at least since Visual C++ 2005; the version of g++ you are using may not support it.

As for how you get this working with g++, it depends.  If you don't have any code that relies on a particular underlying type, then you can just remove it.  If you do have code that relies on a particular underlying type, you might consider replacing uses of the enumeration type with the underlying type (i.e., use `UINT32` instead of `nameofenum`); this isn't very nice, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. UINT32 is unsigned 32bit integer, so your enum is representated by 4bytes int.
2. It depends. I dont' know exactly, but do you really need to use this enum as 32bit int? May be you just can avoid this :UINT32 declaration?

Answer (score 0):

`: UINT` means that the underlying type of the enumeration identifiers is `UINT`.
It is a Microsoft extension described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28VS.80%29.aspx). To make it compile remove `: UINT`.